# Laravel Middleware redirects forever

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

Can anybody help me with middleware please? I am getting an endless redirect which is driving me crazy for a week now.

```php
/****** Route **********/
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/profile', 'UserController@profile');

    // Superadmin & Admin
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function() {
        Route::get('/dashboard', 'UserController@dashboard');
    });

    // Superadmin
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'superadmin'], function() {
            Route::get('/settings', 'UserController@settings');
    });
});

/****** Middleware *******/
// admin
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        if (User::isAdmin()) { // validate if superadmin or admin
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect('/profile');
    } 
}

// superadmin
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
    if (User::isSuperAdmin()) { // validate if superadmin
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        return redirect('/profile');
    }
    }
}
```

Ok just updated the code again but still having issue that 
redirects forever any ideas?

```
// SuperAdmin
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (!User::isSuperAdmin()) {
                return new RedirectResponse(url('/profile'));
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

// admin and superadmin
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (!User::isAdmin()) {
                return new RedirectResponse(url('/profile'));
            }
        } 

        return $next($request);
    }

// auth
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('/login');
            }
        }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: Please include the code as part of your question, external links may become inaccessible over time.

Comment: What's the URL you are accessing that is triggering the redirect loop? Also please post the code for the `auth` middleware.

Comment: update code above. can you please check?

Comment: I've tested your updated code and it works just fine for me. What URL are you accessing when you are triggering the redirect loop?

Comment: odd. pretty much all of the link if im just an admin

Comment: I'm adding this comment so that this can be found on Google like how I'd search for it: Redirected too many times RedirectIfAuthenticated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. The cause was because both $middleeware and $routeMiddleware is using same middleware

```
protected $middleware = [
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
        //'App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware',
        //'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth'          => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic'    => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest'         => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'admin'         => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
        'superadmin'    => 'App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware',
    ];
```

Comment: The issue is `$middleware` runs on each requests while `$routeMiddleware` can be applied specifically to a route, or controller and runs only when needed.